# Is there an XML alternative to iOS storyboards?

Tags: xml, xcode, storyboard, xib

Is there something like XML in Xcode?

I have been trying to use storyboards but have found them to be slow, not performance wise, but workflow wise. After using storyboards for a bit dragging and dropping views manually from the storyboard to the Swift file feels slower than just referencing them programmatically.

I would rather not create the UI completely programmatically as that sounds just as bad if not worse. I have seen people use `.xib` but would xib be more my style and is it out of date (meaning should I just use storyboard because that's what Apple is working on)?

Perhaps there is something to storyboards I am just missing. Anyways thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no other option other than creating the UI programmatically.

Xib is not deprecated, it is still a good way to create reusable `UIViews`. Storyboards provide more control of the flow with `UIViewControllers` and segues.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was posted a while ago, but in case it is of interest - MarkupKit is an open-source project I created specifically to address this type of use case:

https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit

It allows you to build native iOS apps declaratively using XML, similar to how applications are built for Android.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know there is an alternate way of using storyboard's in *XML* form all you have to do is:-

```
1.Right click on the storyBoard.

2.Open as > Source code
```

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks for the tip this is cool but not really what im looking for. The point is to find something that would make the workflow a bit faster but the sheer amount of xml in a storyboard compared to an android layout file defeats the initial purpose of this post.

Comment: yes you're right but i think programmatically you can achieve the speed as compared to the IDE.